# Check if a dictionary is subset of another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to compare 2 Strings and check if all characters in String `a` are present in String `b`. I am currently using the following method by converting the string into a dictionary and comparing it with the other. But there are many chances that it gives a false positive.

```
x = 'NJITZU THE HANDS OF TIME'
y = 'NinjaGo Masters of Spinjitzu The Hands of Time'
if Counter(x) < Counter(y):
    print 'Yes'
else:
    print 'No'
```

Please suggest any better way to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you don't need to compare dictionaries, but sets:

```
>>> x = 'NJITZU THE HANDS OF TIME'
>>> y = 'NinjaGo Masters of Spinjitzu The Hands of Time'
>>> set(x).issubset(set(y))
False
```

And if you want a case-insensitive compare, you can call `lower()` on both strings:

```
>>> set(x.lower()).issubset(set(y.lower()))
True
```

You could also compare whole words by using `split()`:

```
>>> set(x.lower().split())
set(['of', 'the', 'time', 'njitzu', 'hands'])
>>> set(x.lower().split()).issubset(set(y.lower().split()))
False
>>> set('SPINJITZU THE HANDS OF TIME'.lower().split()).issubset(set(y.lower().split()))
True
```

Comment: Only note I might add is that it's not clear whether OP wants to include space characters.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `set` object. [Documentation can be found here.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set)

```
x = 'NJITZU THE HANDS OF TIME'
y = 'NinjaGo Masters of Spinjitzu The Hands of Time'
if set(x.lower()) <= set(y.lower()):
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

The `<` operator is overloaded to be `is_subset`.  To get the answer to print "Yes", I've also converted the strings to lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builtin [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function for this.

```
all(character in y for character in x)
```

all() will return true if every element is true and false otherwise. We use `in` to check if a character is in the string `y` and we will do this for every `character in x`.

Comment: This works fine and is pretty readable. It's much less efficient than using sets, though.

Comment: The problem is that you have to call `character in y` for each `character in x`, and it's expensive to parse the whole `y` string again and again. Using another `all()` shouldn't change the `O(n*m)` complexity. With sets, complexity should be `O(n+m)`.

Comment: That ... should have been obvious to me. Thanks.